# How can I protect a key against other applications?

Tags: security, sqlite, storage

**Setup**

1. I have a SQLite database which has confidential user information.
2. This database may be replicated on other machines
3. I trust the user, but not other applications
4. The user has occasional access to a global server

**Security Goals**

1. Any program other than the authorized one (mine) cannot access the SQLite database.
2. Breaking the security on one machine will NOT break the security on other machines
3. The system must be updatable (meaning that if some algorithm such as a specific key generation algorithm is shown to be flawed, it can be changed)

**Proposed Design**

Use an encrypted SQLite database storing the key within OS secure storage.

**Problems**

Any windows hack will allow the person to access the key for all machines which violates goal #2

**Notes**

1. Similar to this method, if I store the key in the executable, breaking the security will comprimise all systems.
2. Also, I have referenced windows secure storage. While, I will go to an os specific solution if I have to, I would prefer a non-os specific solution

Any idea on how to meet the design goals?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use TPM hardware e.g. via TBS or something similar, to actually make a secure version of this. My understanding is, TPM lets the application check that it is not being debugged or traced at a software level, and the operating system should prevent any other application pretending to the TPM module that it is your application. I may be wrong though.

You can use some kind of security-through-obscurity kludge, but it will be crackable with a debugger unless you use TPM.